# How to time the amount of time a message takes to be sent to a computer and back

Tags: java

i have written some code that sends a message to a machine, and then replies, i am wondering how i could time, the amount of time it takes for the message to be sent to the other computer and then back ?

here is the code i have so far :

```
import mpi.* ;

class Hello {
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    MPI.Init(args) ;
    int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
    if(myrank == 0) {
      char[] mess = " Raptor" .toCharArray();
      MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(mess, 0, mess.length, MPI.CHAR, 1, 99);
    } else {
      char[] mess = new char [20];
      MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(mess, 0, 20, MPI.CHAR, 0, 99);
      System.out.println("received:"+new String(mess)+":");
    }
    MPI.Finalize();
  }
}
```

Sorry if it is a simple question, first time using mpi !

EDIT:

code now is :

```
import mpi.* ;

class Hello {

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    MPI.Init(args) ;
    int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
    if(myrank == 0) {
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
      char[] mess = " Hello, there" .toCharArray();
      MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(mess, 0, mess.length, MPI.CHAR, 1, 99);
    } else {
      char[] mess = new char [20];
      MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(mess, 0, 20, MPI.CHAR, 0, 99);
      System.out.println("received:"+new String(mess)+":");
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

long duration = endTime - startTime;
system.out.println(duration);
    MPI.Finalize();
  }
}
```

but am now getting these errors on compile :

javac Hello.java

```
Hello.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
long duration = endTime - startTime;
                ^
  symbol:   variable endTime
  location: class Hello
Hello.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
long duration = endTime - startTime;
                          ^
  symbol:   variable startTime
  location: class Hello
Hello.java:20: error: package system does not exist
system.out.println(duration);
      ^
3 errors
```

Comment: You declared the times inside an if/else block and are trying to print them outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// send & receive
...
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

---

```
MPI.Init(args);
int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
if (myrank == 0) {
     ...
} else {
      ...
}

long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am now getting 3 errors, what have i done wrong ?

Comment: Thanks :), is now perfect, great starting block for my aim :) thanks a lot